# grep multiple strings from file

Tags: grep

I have used the following command to get unique list of each name from my file

```
grep -oP "name_\w*" file_copy.txt | sort |uniq > list.txt
FILE=list.txt
while read line; do
     cat file_copy.txt | grep "$line" | wc -l 
     cat file_copy.txt | grep $line | grep "name" | grep $line+1 -v | wc -l
```

Last command is not running the way i expected

---

**list.txt** files like below: 
USA
Russia
Japan

**file_copy.tx**t

USA Russia Russia Russia Japan  
Japan Japan USA USA Russia
Japan Japan USA USA Russia
Japan Russia USA USA Russia

Comment: would be a good idea to add sample input and expected output as well

Comment: @Sundeep I have two files one is list_txt where I have some unique names like a,b,c etc and second file which is file_copy.txt  where i would like to search and count these names to create a venn. And I want combinations of two and  invert-match(-v) for third.

Comment: that is not clear, at least to me.. what I would suggest is create sample files for list_txt,  file_copy.txt and add complete expected output for that to question...

Answer (score 1):

Replace last line to:

```
grep -c -e "$line" -e "name" -e $((line+1))
```

You can define more condition with parameter `-e`, and wc is useless, grep can count matches with `-c`

Answer (score 0):

For a given `input` file:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

If you want to get a count for any lines matching, say, `e` and `b`:

```
$ grep -c -e 'e' -e 'b'
2
```

Comment: Thank you @DopeGhoti, I would like do invert-match(-v) for one of the character and check the overlapping to create a Venn. So the Idea is to match these names in another files to count overlapping numbers

Comment: You might want to look into `comm`.